# simply rendering data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

i'm trying my hardest to wrap my head around this concept and after wasting a couple hours i figured id try and see if someone would kindly fix and elaborate upon such a simple matter

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        marketdata: [],
        loading: true
    }
  }


componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/global')
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ marketdata: data })
      console.log(this.state.marketdata.data.market_cap_change_percentage_24h_usd)
     })
}

...

render() {

    const { coindata, marketdata} = this.state;

    <p>{marketdata.data.market_cap_change_percentage_24h_usd}</p>
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'market_cap_change_percentage_24h_usd' of undefined

i want to be able to better understand so i can carry on and not get stuck when trying to consume data from APIs throughout this entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what `this.setState()` does, but I assume it should set the member `state`.

The problem is that you try to access a member of an object while that object does not exist. So, you should change

`this.state.marketdata.data.market_cap_change_percentage_24h_usd`

to

`this.state.marketdata.market_cap_change_percentage_24h_usd`

`{ marketdata: data }` does not mean that the new property is `marketdata.data` but the colon (`:`) is an assignment just like `=`, so `marketdata` gets the value of `data`.

If that does not work try to console.log from "up to bottom" which means first log `this.state` , then `this.state.marketdata` and so on, until you see what you received and set.

Comment: i worked my way down, console.log'in myself afloat! i managed to better understand this myself after tinkering around with my code for a while :) thanks!